# Set onItemClick listener for ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to set an `OnItemClickListener` for my ListView in Android, but i can't get it to work.

This is what i have so far:

```
public class MenuFragment extends SherlockFragment
{
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_mainmenu);

    // some code here where i add items to an ArrayList...

    // Then i add the ArrayList to an EntryAdapter
    EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), items);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setClickable(true);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error on `OnItemClickListener()`:

> The method OnItemClickListener() is undefined for the type AdapterView.

So my qyestion is, how can i set an `OnItemClickListener` on my ListView??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check this code

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have imported correct packages:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **should implement a customAdapter** for having more control on your listView, [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) is the link after visiting this you should be able to do what is required. Or you can have this code to quickly do what you need.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long itemID) {


}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

        }
    });
```